# How to bound $E \left[\left(E[Z^2\mid Y] \right)^2\right]- 2E \left[ |E[Z\mid Y]| \sqrt{E[Z^2\mid Y]} \right]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, parameter-estimation

I am looking for an upper bound on the following quantity
\begin{align*}
A=E \left[\left(E[Z^2\mid Y] \right)^2\right]- 2E \left[ |E[Z\mid Y]| \sqrt{E[Z^2\mid Y]} \right]
\end{align*}
where $Z$ is standard Gaussian and $Y=Z+W$ where $Z$ and $W$ are independent and $E[W^2]\le 1$.

Here is some bounds I was able to come up with:

**Bound 1**
\begin{align*}
A=E \left[\left(E[Z^2\mid Y] \right)^2\right]- 2E \left[ |E[Z\mid Y]| \sqrt{E[Z^2\mid Y]} \right] &\le  E \left[\left(E[Z^2\mid Y] \right)^2\right]\\
& \le E[Z^4] =3
\end{align*}

**Bound 2**
\begin{align*}
A=E \left[\left(E[Z^2\mid Y] \right)^2\right]- 2E \left[ |E[Z\mid Y]| \sqrt{E[Z^2\mid Y]} \right] &\le  E \left[\left(E[Z^2\mid Y] \right)^2\right]- E \left[ |E[Z\mid Y]| |E[Z\mid Y]| \right] \\
&=E \left[\left(E[Z^2\mid Y] \right)^2\right]- 2E \left[  (E[Z\mid Y])^2 \right]\\
&=3- 2E \left[  (E[Z\mid Y])^2 \right]
\end{align*}

Note, that having about in terms of $E \left[  (E[Z\mid Y])^2 \right]$ is acceptable for me. 
My question can we push bound in 2 even lower ??

I am also looking for any suggestion or tricks that you might have that can help  with bounding.

Thank you